# Transpose output of PROC UNIVARIATE:TestsForLocation

Tags: sas

I want to format the result of the following call to PROC UNIVARIATE (TestForLocation).

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class; by sex; run;
proc univariate data = sashelp.class mu0 = 1;
  ods select TestsForLocation;
  var age;
  by sex;
  ods output TestsForLocation=ttest;
run;
data ttest; set ttest; keep sex test stat pvalue;run;
proc print data=ttest;run;
```

[image]

How can I trasnpose the output into a datset with the following columns?

```
Obs, Sex, StudentsT_Stat, StudentsT_pValue, SignedRank_Stat, SignedRank_Pvalue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double transpose here.  Make a dataset with 12 observations, with four columns: `Obs`, `Sex`, `ID` being the combination of Test and (Stat|pValue) that you want as your eventual variable name, and `Value` being the value you want transposed into the variable.  Then,

```
proc transpose data=ttest_double out=ttest_transposed;
by obs sex;
id ID;
var Value;
run;
```

(`ID` and `Value` can be any variable name you like.)

Comment: Great. Got it done. `proc transpose data=ttest out=ttest_double;
by sex test;
var stat pvalue;
run;
proc print;run;

proc transpose data=ttest_double out=ttest_transposed;
by sex;
id test _Name_;
var COL1;
run;
proc print;run;`